# Where can a person rent a motorcycle in Palo Alto or Mountain View (California, USA)?

Tags: usa, california, motorcycles, silicon-valley

It's all in the question, I am looking for places where I can rent a bike, in Palo Alto or Mountain View. And whether I have to bring my own gear or I can rent a helmet as well.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As a reminder, questions on Stack Exchange should demonstrate some initial research effort so that we do not duplicate work. For example, what did a web search reveal, considering that is the first thing a potential answerer would conduct?

Comment: To expand on @choster's comment, it would help if you could give at least some idea of why you're asking here. Have you had trouble finding a source for motorcycle rentals there?  Did you find places that didn't meet your needs for some reason?

Comment: If you Google "motorcycle rental mountain view" you will see at least a dozen results.

Answer (score 1):

There are several! I guess you'd want a list or the 'best', so I've tried to accommodate that by linking to the [Yelp list of such places in Palo Alto](https://www.yelp.com.au/search?cflt=motorcycle_rental&find_loc=Palo+Alto%2C+CA).

The currently 'top rated' one there is Dubbelju Motorcycle Rental, at  274 Shotwell St
San Francisco, CA 94110
United States

Phone number (415) 495-2774

Comment: Yelp has a fascinating definition of "near" there, but I guess there really aren't very many options anywhere near Palo Alto. That's in San Francisco 30+ miles away (and with traffic, that can be a long 30 miles, though I guess you can beat some of that traffic once you have a motorcycle).